# Connection between Majorana and boson operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bosons, majorana-fermions

I recently was thinking about the mathematical similarity between two very different physical systems.  For bosons, we can write down the usual canonical relations
\begin{align}
b &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x + ip)\\
b^\dagger &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x - ip)
\end{align}
where $x$ and $p$ are Hermitian observables.  Though physically quite different, there is a similar set of relations for fermions
\begin{align}
f &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\gamma_1 + i\gamma_2)\\
f^\dagger &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\gamma_1 - i\gamma_2)
\end{align}
where $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are Majorana operators, which means they are also Hermitian, so that creation is the same as annihilation.  I am not well-versed in the theory of Majoranas, but whenever I see relations this similar, I assume there must be a connection.  Is there some sense in which the Majorana operators, which normally refer to particles, can be thought of as canonically conjugate observables of fermions?  Is that just an equivalent definition?  Obviously one can't take this too far, because for $x$ and $p$ we also have classical analogies (i.e. Ehrenfest's Theorem), but $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are certainly not interpretable in the same way.  Nonetheless, I wonder if there is an underlying connection (perhaps related to Bogoliubov transforms, but again, I don't know enough about them to say anything concrete).  In a line, my question is whether these two sets of equations are unified in some more general theory that I am just not aware of, or if there is a flaw in this comparison.